# Prove that is $f$ i surjective, then $[a]_n$ is a unit.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Let $[a]_n \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ with $[a]_n \neq 0$. Define a function $f: \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ by $f: [b]_n \rightarrow [b]_n \cdot [a]_n$.

1. Prove that is $f$ is surjective, then $[a]_n$ is a unit.
2. Also, prove that if $f$ is not injective, then $[a]_n$ is a zero divisor.

I am having trouble seeing how $f$ being surjective has a connection to $[a]_n$ being a unit, i.e. $\exists [x]_n \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ s.t. $[a]_n \cdot [x]_n = [1]_n$. (Similarly with 2. I do not see the connection, but I figured once I see 1. is would become more apparent.)

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is surjective, $1$ has an inverse image under $f$. Which means that it exists $b \in \mathbb Z_n$ such that $b\cdot a=1$. This also means that $a$ is a unit.

And if $f$ is not injective, it exists $b_1 \neq b_2$ such that $b_1 \cdot a=b_2 \cdot a$. Therefore $(b_1-b_2)\cdot a=0$, proving that $a$ is a zero divisor as $b_1-b_2 \neq 0$.